# angularJS {{variable}} can't be displayed in script tag

Tags: html, angularjs, show

```
<script type="text/template">
     <div class="abcd">
           <div class="efg" data-price="{{::displayPrice}}"></div>
     </div>
</script>
```

I have got a template like this, and I need to add `{{::displayPrice}}`, which is a variable in the scope, to the `div`'s data-price part. However the `div` is written in a `<script>` tag, which cause it to not work.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: it's a div tag in a script tag

Comment: is it inside a controller?

Comment: I'm all in if you can explain to me how you create a variable starting with ::

Comment: Hi Asqan , 
No, it's in the html template , the {{::displayPrice}} is from directive though .

Comment: Hi YannickHelmut 
the :: only means that this variable is one-time binding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can turn it into angular template using `type="text/ng-template"`, this way angular will compile it with all available on current scope variables:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id"/my-template.html">
 <div class="abcd">
   <div class="efg" data-price="{{::displayPrice}}"></div>
 </div>
```

now you can use it as router template or as `ng-include="'my-template.html'"`.

If you cannot change template type, than in your controller you can compile templates' HTML (using jQuery for example and `$compile` service), something like:

```
var yourAngularTpl = jQuery('[type="text/template"]').eq(0).html();
yourAngularTpl = $complie(yourAngularTpl)($scope);
```

make sure `$scope` and `$complie` are injected and you have `jQuery` (as jQuery Light `angular.element()` is limited)

Comment: I solved this problem by re-write the html .
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

in angular we used to use 
in your controller(app.js)

```
$scope.price = "display some price";
```

in your html

```
<div>{{price}}</div>
```